# API to solve the CORS problem ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: reactjs, api

I am currently on an API where I am trying to retrieve data with the "GET" method.
I used the AXIOS library to retrieve my data.
But the problem I'm having is that when I want to retrieve it I get this error message in my console that blocks me with CORS: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/champions' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

My function to retrieve my data :

```
function Champions() {
    const token = "...."

    useEffect(() => {
      const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" :"http://localhost:8080/champions"
      };
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/champions", { headers })
        .then((response) => console.log(response));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Coucou</h1>
        </div>
    )
  }

export default Champions;
```

proxy attempt (non-functional) :

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware")

module.exports = app =>  {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware('/champions',
        {
            target: "http://localhost:8080",
            ChangeOrigin: true,
        })
    )
}
```

Should I make a proxy? (I tried different tutorials without success...)
Or should I add something in my Headers function that refers to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'?

Comment: Try with `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" :"*"`

Comment: without success either ...

Comment: The dev proxy isn't going to help unless your requests _actually go to it_. At the moment, they're trying to go directly to the server, bypassing the proxy entirely. And whether or not the proxy is an appropriate solution depends on whether you will need to handle CORS in production or not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So if the proxy is not so interesting in my case. 
How can I allow it access and get the result of my request?

Comment: Add the appropriate headers to the response on the server - research how to do that for whatever your backend is implemented in.

Answer (score 0):

I think CORS issue is common in Chrome. Came across an [article](https://medium.com/swlh/avoiding-cors-errors-on-localhost-in-2020-5a656ed8cefa), which might help you for atleast in the development phase(Not tried it though).